# Проверить 100к url взятых из txt файла на 404 php

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

Есть большое количество url. Необходимо проверить, какие ещё существуют, а какие нет. Я попробовал через:

```
<?php
function get_http_response_code($theURL) {
 $headers = get_headers($theURL);
 return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
 }
$result = file("test1.txt");
for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) { 
$theURL = $result[$i];
if(get_http_response_code($theURL) == '404'){
echo $theURL;
}
}
?>
```

и у меня не хочет обрабатывать url из файла.
ошибка: "get_headers() [function.get-headers]: This function may only be used against URLs" 
вопрос - почему?

Comment: Есть ли какие то ошибки ? Возможно ваш IP блокирует хост, из за частых обращений, проверерьте только несколько ссылок, без цикла.

Comment: Как вы определяете, что не хочет обрабатывать?

Comment: @Arsen добавил ошибку "get_headers() [function.get-headers]: This function may only be used against URLs"

Comment: думаю у вас проблемы с настройками в php.ini

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16267057/4496422

Comment: вы уверены, что у вас в файле только URL? выведите ту URL, на которой выпадает ошибка

Comment: и да, 100к адресов проверить чтобы придется увеличить лимит выполнения скрипта на пару-тройку часов, и вывод в консоль неправильных  ссылок лучше перенаправить в файл, ибо их может быть довольно много.

Comment: Лучше поставьте проверку на то что возвращает эта функция и записывайте те адреса, по которым она вернула false. Учитесь читать документацию и просчитывать сценарии работы (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php)

Comment: Может лучше заюзать curl_multi?